# how to remove set of dates from given date and return start and end end date using php

Tags: php

my original date start 01 Jan 2013 end 18 Feb 2016 and i want to remove 25 Mar 2015 to 15 Oct 2015 then my output is start 01 Jan 2013 end is 24 Mar 2014 and start 16 Oct 2014 end is 18 Feb 2016

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, siva! Unfortunately your question is unsuitable for this site. We'll be happy to help you with the specific problems you encounter while programming your stuff, but you have to **add more details** and **show more relevant code.**  **You can edit questions using ‘edit’ link below tags list.** Please see **“[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”** for more information.

Comment: To clarify, you have a `$startDate` and an `$endDate` and you want to be able to loop through all the dates between `$startDate` and `$endDate` but you want to exclude certain periods from the loop, i.e. *25/03/2015 to 15/10/2015*?

Comment: $original[0]["start"] = "01-01-2013"; 
$original[0]["end"] = "18-02-2016"; 


$conditionDate["start"] = "25-03-2014";
$conditionDate["end"] = "15-10-2014";
then

output must be

$original[0]["start"] = "01-01-2013"; 
$original[0]["end"] = "24-03-2014"; 
$original[1]["start"] = "16-10-2014"; 
$original[1]["end"] = "18-02-2016";

Comment: $original has start & end date

Comment: i want to remove $conditionDate from $original

Comment: and then.. output look like

Comment: $original[0]["start"] = "01-01-2013"; 
$original[0]["end"] = "24-03-2014";

Comment: $original[1]["start"] = "16-10-2014"; 
$original[1]["end"] = "18-02-2016";

Comment: i have an answer but unable to post proper format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dateArr = array();
$arr_1   = array();
$arr_2   = array();
$begin   = new DateTime('2013-01-01 00:00:00');
$end     = new DateTime('2016-02-18 23:59:59');
$daterange  = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);
foreach($daterange as $date){
   $arr_1[]=  $date->format("Y-m-d");
}
$condidateStart = new DateTime('2014-03-25 00:00:00');
$condidateEnd   = new DateTime('2014-10-15 23:59:59');
$daterange1    = new DatePeriod($condidateStart, new DateInterval('P1D'), $condidateEnd);
foreach($daterange1 as $date){
  $arr_2[] =  $date->format("Y-m-d");
}
$i=0;
$j=0;
$arrcount =  count($arr_1);
for ($m=0;$m<$arrcount;$m++) {
  if(in_array($arr_1[$m],$arr_2)) {
   if($i == 1) {
 $myDateArr[$j]['end'] = $arr_1[$m-1];
 $j = $j+1;
 $i=0;  
     $dateArr="";
   }        
 } 
else {
if($i == 0 || $m == $arrcount-1) { 
 if($m == $arrcount-1) { 
  $myDateArr[$j]['end'] = $arr_1[$m];
$j = $j+1;
 } 
else  {
  $myDateArr[$j]['start'] = $arr_1[$m]; 
$i=1; 
}
   $dateArr=""; 
 }
 }      
 }
echo"<pre>";print_r($myDateArr);
```